# How can I mark a flow with iptables?

Tags: linux, iptables

I read this [tutorial](https://home.regit.org/netfilter-en/links-load-balancing/), however I am considering a method to load balancing for Internet connection by applying iptables rule on 2 interfaces. The following is my iptables rule.

```
#!/bin/sh

IPT="/sbin/iptables"

LAN='ens38'
WAN='ens33'
OPT='ens37'

LAN_NET="192.168.100.0/24"

$IPT -F
$IPT -X
$IPT -t nat -F

$IPT -P INPUT DROP
$IPT -P OUTPUT DROP
$IPT -P FORWARD DROP


$IPT -A FORWARD -i $LAN -o $WAN -j ACCEPT
$IPT -A FORWARD -i $LAN -o $OPT -j ACCEPT


$IPT -A FORWARD -i $WAN -o $LAN -j ACCEPT
$IPT -A FORWARD -i $OPT -o $LAN -j ACCEPT

$IPT -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o $WAN -j MASQUERADE
$IPT -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o $OPT -j MASQUERADE


# Load balancing rules (Split 50/50 between fwmark 1/2)
$IPT -t mangle -N balance1
$IPT -t mangle -A balance1 -m connmark ! --mark 0 -j RETURN
$IPT -t mangle -A balance1 -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j RETURN
$IPT -t mangle -A balance1 -m statistic --mode nth --every 2 --packet 0 -j CONNMARK --set-mark 1
$IPT -t mangle -A balance1 -m statistic --mode nth --every 2 --packet 1 -j CONNMARK --set-mark 2

# Check to see if we have already marked a packet
$IPT -t mangle -A PREROUTING  -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j CONNMARK --restore-mark
$IPT -t mangle -A OUTPUT      -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j CONNMARK --restore-mark

# Mark incoming connections to return on the interface they came in on
$IPT -t mangle -A PREROUTING          -i $WAN                     -m state --state NEW  -j CONNMARK --set-mark 1
$IPT -t mangle -A PREROUTING          -i $OPT                     -m state --state NEW  -j CONNMARK --set-mark 2

# New outgoing packets
$IPT -t mangle -A PREROUTING  -i $LAN          -p tcp --dport 80 -m state --state NEW  -j balance1
$IPT -t mangle -A PREROUTING  -i $LAN          -p tcp --dport 443 -m state --state NEW  -j balance1
# $IPT -t mangle -A OUTPUT                       -p tcp --dport  80 -m state --state NEW  -j balance1

# Choose our route and save the mark
$IPT -t mangle -A PREROUTING  -m connmark --mark 1 -j MARK --set-mark 1
$IPT -t mangle -A PREROUTING  -m connmark --mark 2 -j MARK --set-mark 2
$IPT -t mangle -A PREROUTING  -m state --state NEW -m connmark ! --mark 0  -j CONNMARK --save-mark


echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
```

I defined 2 table wan and opt in `/etc/iproute2/rt_tables` like the following:

```
[root@R1 ~]# cat /etc/iproute2/rt_tables 
#
# reserved values
#
255 local
254 main
253 default
0   unspec
#
# local
#
1   wan
2   opt
```

This is the script that I add route for iproute:

```
LAN_DEV='ens38'
WAN_DEV='ens33'
OPT_DEV='ens37'

WAN_GW="192.168.84.2"
OPT_GW="192.168.0.1"

LAN_NET="192.168.100.0/24"


ip rule add fwmark 1 table wan
ip rule add fwmark 2 table opt

# Add default route for table wan and opt
ip route add default via $WAN_GW dev $WAN_DEV table wan
ip route add default via $OPT_GW dev $OPT_DEV table opt

# Add LAN route for table wan and opt

ip route add $LAN_NET dev $LAN_DEV table opt
ip route add $LAN_NET dev $LAN_DEV table wan
```

As I understood from this [guide](http://security.maruhn.com/iptables-tutorial/x9125.html), `restore-mark` and `save-mark`  restore and save the packet mark from the connection mark. So the rules apply for **every packet** in **a connection**. For example: I have a connection A. iptables rules count every 4 packets in connection A and mark it 1,2,1,2.

How can I mark a connection separately in case I have many connections. For example: I have 3 connections A,B,C and I want to count and mark them like: 1,2,3.

Actually, this rule uses route from WAN (ens33) only. When the packet come in to router. It not route to OPT (ens37) which I can not explain.

Comment: I found this [link](https://blog.khax.net/2009/12/01/multi-gateway-balancing-with-iptables/) but it does not work. :(

Answer (score 2):

You need a rule to accept the connections already known, without re-marking them.

This way, only the new connections will trigger the counter.

```
iptables -A PREROUTING -t mangle -j CONNMARK --restore-mark
iptables -A PREROUTING -t mangle -m mark ! --mark 0 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A PREROUTING -t mangle -m mark --mark 0 -m nth --counter 1 \
--every 3 --packet 1 -j MARK --set-mark 1
iptables -A PREROUTING -t mangle -m mark --mark 0 -m nth --counter 1 \
--every 3 --packet 2 -j MARK --set-mark 2
iptables -A PREROUTING -t mangle -m mark --mark 0 -m nth --counter 1 \
--every 3 --packet 3 -j MARK --set-mark 3
iptables -A POSTROUTING -t mangle -j CONNMARK --save-mark
```

Comment: Could you edit with a completely rule?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand your question. What edition do you need?

Comment: @Sanel I updated iptables and iproute. Please take a look.

Comment: Doesn't your last script output 2 errors ? You should execute `ip route add $LAN_NET` first, `ip route add default` then. Could you post the result of `ip rule list` too ?